# a syntax error of python: print ' ... ' always have error

Tags: python, windows-7

This python3.3 code on win 7, why I got error:

```
import random

guesses_made = 0

name = raw_input('Hello! What is your name?\n')

number = random.randint(1, 20)
print "Well, {0}, I am thinking of a number between 1 and 20" # error here !!!


**print "Well, {0}, I am thinking of a number between 1 and 20"
                                                            ^
 SyntaxError: invalid syntax**
```

Thanks !!!

Comment: Shouldn't you get a `NameError` at `raw_input`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

In python 3, `raw_input()` [has been changed](http://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#builtins) to `input()`.

Also, [`print` is no longer a statement but a function](http://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#print-is-a-function), so you must do:

```
print("Well, {0}, I am thinking of a number between 1 and 20")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that last line should read:

```
print("Well, {0}, I am thinking of a number between 1 and 20".format(name))
```

This was tested. I am pretty new to p3.3, so go easy on me :)